# Smaller resolution makes images tiny (bootstrap-5 Fluid)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

**What is happening currently:**
When using the Chrome browser device toolbar tool to test out my site at different resolutions, I noticed that when I shrink the device screen down to "Mobile-s" 320px, the content on my page becomes almost unreadable. This also causes images to be exreamly small, not to mention sentences broken down to the poiont where single letters are stacked on top of each other.

**What I would like to happen:** I would like for the content in the card to shrink as the screen resolution is reduced, but also become readable and have the image stay large enough to be seen.

What I'm using in my project:

1. html
2. css
3. Booststrap 5

Here is html for my blog section:

You can see that I'm using **container-fluid** in my outer most div.

```
   <h2 class="display-6 mb-5">My blog:</h2>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 ">
                        <div class="card " >
                            <img src="img/1.jpg" class="card-img-top " alt="...">
                            <div class="card-body ">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card 
                                   title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Here is html for my images section:

You can see that I'm also using **container-fluid** in my outer most div.

```
 <h2 class="display-6">My projects:</h2>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row gy-5"> <!--gy-5 will provide spacing between each image -->
                    <div class="col-md-6"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Portfolio image" class="img-fluid thumbnail">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Portfolio image" class="img-fluid thumbnail">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Portfolio image" class="img-fluid thumbnail">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Portfolio image" class="img-fluid thumbnail">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Portfolio image" class="img-fluid thumbnail">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Portfolio image" class="img-fluid thumbnail">
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is what's included in my css:

```
    body, html{
    height: 100%;

}

body{
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #444;
}

.intro-left{
    background: url("../img/1.jpg");/*concrete background*/
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    width: 33.3333%;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;

}

@media(max-width: 768px) { /*@media rule will add the code inside only if the max-width is 768px */
    .intro-left{
        height: 80vh;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }

}

.avatar{
    width: 10rem;
    height: 7em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 1rem;
}

.full-height {
    height: 100%;
}

.quote{
    float: right;
}

section{
    margin: 5rem;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

a{
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

**How the cards currently look on 320px**

[image]

**How the images currently look on 320px**

[image]

**How the cards **SHOULD** look on 320px**

[image]

**How the images **SHOULD** look on 320px**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reducing section margin will increase size of elements. This is because the margin applied to the section class will cause a gap around the whole element. The gap produced with the initial question was at 5rem. As the resolution decreased the gap created by the margin maintained its 5rem thus making the elemets that used the section class become a lot smaller when the screen resultion was decreased. Once this margin was reduced to 0.1rem it reduced the gap around all sides, which caused the elements to become much larger/readable when resolution decreased.

From this:

```
section{
   margin: 5rem; 
   font-size: 1.2rem;
 }
```

To this:

```
section{
   margin: 0.1rem; 
   font-size: 1.2rem;
 }
```

Comment: Please explain how and why this works, and provide a sample code. As a Q&A site, this will help users in the future to understand your solution and implement it themselves.

Answer (score 1):

you defined the size of the DIV of the images within col-md-6, you have to define the classes in different sizes.

Ex:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-3 col-xxl-3">
    <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Portfolio image" class="img-fluid thumbnail">
</div>
```

I recommend studying the Bootstrap Grid System documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#grid-options

Comment: Could you put the entire code in jsfiddle to be able to have more details?